# Difference between `winfo child` and `winfo children`

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I was having a look at the Tk demo widget 8.5/8.6 and found the line inside:

```
eval destroy [winfo child .]
```

When I looked up [`winfo`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/winfo.htm), there was no `child` option, but there was a `children` option. I tested a few things with the two and they appear to be the same.

```
% package require Tk
% pack [label .m1 -text "Hello"]
% pack [label .m2 -text "World"]
% puts [winfo child .]
.m1 .m2
% puts [winfo children .]
.m1 .m2
```

Those two seem to be the same to me, but one is documented and the other isn't. Is there any difference or is that only a consequence of different versions of Tcl (it seems that `child` was used earlier and is now being replaced with `children` -perhaps because of a bug?-, although both behave roughly similarly)?

If they are different, is there any reason why someone would use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tcl allows you to abbreviate any command to the closest non-ambiguous substring. For instance:

```
% string range abcd 0 2
abc
% stri ran abcd 0 2
abc
% str r abcd 0 2
unknown or ambiguous subcommand "r": must be bytelength, compare, equal, first, index, is,  last, length, map, match, range, repeat, replace, reverse, tolower, totitle, toupper, trim, trimleft, trimright, wordend, or wordstart
%
```

The final line has an ambiguous match - r can match any of range, repeat, replace or reverse so we get an error raised. `ra` is the shortest match possible for `range` here.

The specific documentation applicable to this is actually in the man page for [Tcl_GetIndexFromObj](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/GetIndex.htm) where is states

> A match occurs if objPtr's string value is identical to one of the strings in tablePtr, or if it is a non-empty unique abbreviation for exactly one of the strings in tablePtr and the TCL_EXACT flag was not specified

This is because the `Tcl_GetIndexFromObj` API call is typically how commands and subcommands are identified throughout the Tcl sources.

Comment: Wow, that's really surprising... I never knew that Tcl was holding such a capability. Thank you for answering :)

Comment: Btw, this might be a bit off-topic, but would you happen to know whether this is something quite unique to Tcl or are there some other languages with APIs behaving in a similar way?

Comment: The abbreviation of commands is *only* when interactive; the abbreviation of subcommands is always enabled. ***Good Tcl scripts do not use abbreviations.*** There are no long-term guarantees that particular abbreviations will continue to be unique in future versions of Tcl.

Comment: @DonalFellows Thank you for the clarification and it's understandable that proper scripts shouldn't rely on that API for some sort of 'autocomplete' feature. One last thing that bothers me a bit, is that I wouldn't have expected something like that in the demo widget, it's like putting some 'bad practice' in demos.

Comment: @Jerry The prefix handling is baked into the base API, `Tcl_GetIndexFromObj` (except for top-level commands, where it is part of `unknown`). That makes _not_ having expansion actually take _more_ code…